# Порядок структуры меню

Tags: wordpress, menu

Прошу помощи, т.к. сам затупил. Есть вот такое меню — https://mob.akcuoma.ru (меню не вверху, а в середине страницы)
Иконки с помощью шрифта .svg добавлены способом произвольных полей — https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/
Как поставить иконку спереди текста (иконка сверху — текст снизу)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.servicemenu li a {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, действительно работает!

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.